# Graphlab commercial license

Tags: graphlab

Is anyone using Graphlab machine learning modules with a commercial license ? I cannot find any information about a commercial license on their website since they got acquired by Apple.

Thanks, 
Ashish

Comment: I would also like to install graphlab. Did you succeed to get a product key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I found some information that may help. Firstly, Graphlab is an open source and currently doesn't charge. Under section 5 of Turi's terms and conditions, its mentioned and confirmed that it's free of cost for now.
Link : https://turi.com/legal/terms_of_use.html

Also, you may contact them by writing mail on address `936 N 34th St., Suite 208, Seattle, WA 98103.` or by emailing them at:  `contact@turi.com`

I agree that they put less information about commercial use but mentioned renew application for academic use. Since, they did mention commercial use standards and essential credits, you may email them and get confirmed although its clearly mentioned of free usage. I hope that helps!!